# Lambda function returns function name instead of value in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I am having difficulty in understanding the lambda function syntax in python. In particular, I don't understand why the following code shouldn't work:

```
def f(x):
    return lambda x:x**2

f(2)
```

The output that I expect is 4 but the actual output looks like this:

```
<function __main__.<lambda>>
```

What is going on?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a function that returns a function. So you need to call what is returned by `f(2)`. If your looking for currying use functools.partial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call the lambda using `()`:

```
In [1]: def f(x):
   ...:     return (lambda n:n**2)(x)
   ...: 

In [2]: f(3)
Out[2]: 9
```

Or assign the lambda to a var:

```
In [3]: f=lambda x:x**2

In [4]: f(4)
Out[4]: 16
```

Answer (score 2):

`f(2)` returns the lambda.  That is what `<function __main__.<lambda>>` is.  Note that the `x` inside the scope of the lambda is not the same `x` that is passed in as the argument to `f`.  So you could have defined your function with no arguments and it would have the same result.

To call the lambda, you can do `f()(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the lambda function to get the result. Not sure what you are doing with that though.

In your case -

```
f(2)(2)
>>> 4
```

If you just want f to refer to the lambda function, then do -

```
f = lambda x:x**2
f(2)
>>>> 4
```

Do not return it from a function.

Comment: Do not return it from a function. - Why?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.
Your `f` function returns a `lambda` function, which needs to be called.
So to make it work -

```
>>> f(0)(2)
      ^ This can be anything
4
```

Try something like this -

```
>>> f = lambda x:x**2
>>> f(2) 
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the parameter with '()' outside in the function should return the value.

def my_color(x):
return (lambda j: 100 if j== 0 else 200)**(x)**

output:
my_color(0)
=> 100